# javascript: mapping same key to different values

Tags: javascript

i have this data set

```
 'Rain':    'severe thunderstorms',
 'Rain':    'thunderstorms',
 'Rain':    'mixed rain and snow',
 'Rain':    'mixed rain and sleet',
```

i want to store this relationship, tried making dictionary like

```
var dict = {
 'Rain':    'severe thunderstorms',
     'Rain':    'thunderstorms',
     'Rain':    'mixed rain and snow',
     'Rain':    'mixed rain and sleet',
}
```

But when i iterate over this dict , it gives just one element

```
for(item in dict){

        Ti.API.info(item+"...."+ dict[item]))
        }
```

**output** Rain:   mixed rain and sleet

then i realized that key has to be unique, so this dict structure would not work.

Is there is any any i can store this and have access to **all mappings with same key**.

Comment: any other way to do it ?

Comment: The way you're trying to structure it doesn't make sense. What is the relationship of rain to all these values?

Comment: it does make sense....http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var dict = {};
dict["rain"] = ['severe thunderstorms', 'mixed rain and snow', 'mixed rain and sleet'];

for(var propName in dict) {
    var propValue = dict[propName];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use an array to assign multiple values to one property name:

```
var dict = {
 'Rain': ['severe thunderstorms', 'thunderstorms', 
          'mixed rain and snow', 'mixed rain and sleet']
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a=[];
a[0]=1;
a[1]=22;

var b=[];
b[0]=111;
b[1]=222;

var dict = {};
dict['AA']=a;
dict['BB']=b;
```

// Get Specific Key value

```
for(var i=0;i < dict['AA'];i++)
  print (dict['AA'][i]);
```

//Get all the Values in dictionary

```
Object.keys(dict).forEach(function(key) {
     print(dict[key]);
```

});